# Creating a record with foreign key Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

New to DRF 3.7.1 and I'm hitting a problem trying to create an object containing a foreign key using POST. The scenario is I have a student - school model (one school has many students) - example below:

```
class School(models.Model):
    school_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    school_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # other fields omitted

class Student(models.Model):
     student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     # other fields omitted
     school = models.ForeignKey('School')
```

The serializer looks like:

```
class SchoolSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = ('school_id','school_name','school_address')

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    school = SchoolSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_name','school')
```

Assuming a school exists (school_id='ABC') I'm trying to post this JSON to create a student:

```
{
  "student_name": "John Doe",
  "school_id": "ABC"
}
```

but am getting the error:

> AssertionError at /mytest/
>   The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
>   Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `myapp.serializers.StudentSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

Not sure how to fix this - what should I reference for the school foreign key?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an explicit `create` method, as DRF doesn't do this for you by default. For example:

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_name','school')

    def create(self, data):
        school, __ = School.objects.get_or_create(school_id=data["school_id"])
        return Student(student_name=data["student_name"], school=school)
```